# Routing for specific subjects (cars, pedestrians, ..) dynamically

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting, dijkstra

I need create app which will be provide routing for specific category. For example only for cars, only for bikes or only for pedestrians. For importing OSM data I'll used default mapconfig for all way types.

Can you tell me which classes are officialy used for cars, pedestrians and how?

I wants use it into pgr_dijsktra function where I will be able select specific ways.

I'll tried this but not works. When I tried same script without where condition for classes it works, but I need specific category dynamically in condition.:

```
SELECT e.seq, e.path_seq, e.node, e.cost, e.agg_cost, w.name, w.the_geom, w.x1, w.y1, w.x2, w.y2 FROM pgr_dijkstra('
SELECT gid AS id,
     source,
     target,
     cost_s AS cost,
     reverse_cost_s AS reverse_cost
    FROM pgr.ways where class_id in (101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116)',
    35959, 
    19303, 
directed := true)e
left join pgr.ways w on w.gid = e.edge
order by e.seq
```

How can I do that?